# Associate EC2 Key Pair with a user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, key-pair

I am trying to implement audit workflow on AWS and for that I would need to a create temporary SSH key to access EC2 with port-forwarding and somehow associate it with a specific user on AWS so it is possible to audit.
Is there a way to associate AWS key pairs created to access EC2 Bastion with users?

Comment: Instead of using SSH, would you consider using [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html)? It does not need key pairs, it uses IAM permissions and all access is logged in CloudTrail.

Comment: The problem with AWS System Manager is that you wouldn't be able to run a ec2 bastion and have ssh port forwarding to it, which is needed in this case.

Comment: Then please add your actual port-forwarding use-cast to the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) seems ideal for your situation:

- Access is controlled by IAM
- It does not require SSH keys
- Access is logged in CloudTrail
- It **supports port forwarding**

See: [New – Port Forwarding Using AWS System Manager Session Manager | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/)